# Solve: $2^{256} = 95^x$ ... what is $x$?

Tags: problem-solving

I expect the result to be around $40$, but I do not know how to get there?

**Not necessary to read:**

I'm doing this because I'm wondering how many (printable!) characters I need for a password strength of $256$ bit. $256$ bit is $2^{256}$ possibilities. In theory it would take $32$ characters, IF every character had $8$ totally random bits. But since I'm restricted to the printable characters, I only get 95 (space until ~) possibilities per $8$ bits (instead of $256$). That is how I came up with the equation above - which I think is correct, I just don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take logs:

$$ 256 \log_2 2 = x \log_2 95 $$

and then solve for $x$.

Comment: log2 of 2 is 1 and log2 of 95 is ~6,57. Thus my x is 256/6,57 = ~38,96. That means I need 39 characters to get to the 256 bit security level. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take the logarithm of both sides to calculate the answer. The logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function. [This link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) talks about them, in case you haven’t been introduced.

Thus, the answer is found as follows:
$$95^x=2^{256}$$
$$\log_{95}\left(95^x\right)=\log_{95}\left(2^{256}\right)$$
$$x=256 \log_{95}2$$
$$x=\frac{256\log_2{2}}{\log_2 95}$$
$$x=\frac{256}{\log_295}$$